# How do I remove RocketTab ads from Google Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, extension, popup-ads

I have certain `RocketTab` ads intermittently coming when I google something. Here is a screenshot:
[image]
I have checked all the extensions in Google Chrome. Nothing is related to RocketTab. Is there any manual ways that I can find where this irritating `RocketTab` is located so that I can delete it from the terminal or something?

Comment: Are you on public wifi?  Have you tried deleting your Chrome profile and starting with a fresh Chrome profile?  Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: No. I'm on home or university wifi.

Comment: How did you check the extensions? Did you actually disable them until you found that the behavior stopped?

Comment: Yes but I guess I was not rigorous enough. Found the issue. Adding as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. It was one of Google Chrome extension named [Facebook video downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-video-downloader/amjcoehkcacocffpmhnefgoeanepjfkf?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). Beware of this extension. It shows ads by `RocketTab` and `Not Set Ads`.